# Counting divs from an online website with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to count the number of divs with the class "item milspec" on a website. When I run my code, the number of divs with the class "item milspec" is printed as 0. Why?

```
import urllib2
import lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://g2case.com/en"
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read(), "lxml")

milspecs = soup.findAll("div", {"class": "item milspec"})

print(len(milspecs))
```

Comment: Probably because the website content is generated/modified by `JavaScript`.

Comment: I would recommend headless browser + selenium

Comment: If using `Selenium`, you can ensure an element is loaded either by using `implicitly_wait(seconds)`, which only needs to be called once before processing (e.g. `driver.implicitly_wait(15)`). This would apply to anything accessed by the driver.

Comment: Otherwise, WebDriverWait could be used for individually accessed elements. After importing WebDriverWait, By, and expected_conditions from selenium.webdriver,  the following would retrieve an element only after it has been loaded: `element = WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, path)))`

Answer (score 1):

The page source if generated/modified by `JavaScript`. `urllib2` will give you only the server response. You need to wait for the client side code to  finish and then get the page source. This can be done with `selenium`.

To install `selenium`

```
pip install selenium
```

And then try the following

```
from time import sleep

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

url = 'http://g2case.com/en'
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(url)


def check_for_div_class_count(html, class_name):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    milspecs = soup.findAll('div', {'class': class_name})
    return len(milspecs)

print check_for_div_class_count(browser.page_source, 'item milspec')
sleep(3)
print check_for_div_class_count(browser.page_source, 'item milspec')

browser.close()
```

**Edit**

To install `chromedriver`

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.21/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
rm chromedriver_linux64.zip
chmod 777 chromedriver
sudo mkdir -p /opt/google/
sudo mv -f chromedriver /opt/google/
sudo ln -s /opt/google/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: When I import selenium, it says that webdriver is an unresolved import

Comment: Did you `pip install selenium` in terminal yet?

Comment: What would I input for Google Chrome?

Comment: First you need to install `chromedriver` https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/ and then `webdriver.Chrome()`

Comment: What would I do if I wanted to check again after 3 seconds, without having to restart the browser?

Comment: The webpage can't be refreshed because then the amount of divs on the page is reset. Anyway to get around this?

Comment: just remove the `browser.refresh()` line